# How can I tell which file failed in a SQL Server SSIS MULTIFLATFILE connection when loading into a table from the files?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am loading 30 files at a time using a MULTIFLATFILE connection from SSIS into a raw table. These files are constantly coming in and a job loops through to exec the package and pick these up. Some of the files can have bad data every once in a while. I am having trouble when one of the 30 files is bad. I have no way to know which of the files actually failed so I can move it into a Suspect folder, roll the other 29 files back into my Input folder and try again. Can't find any info on the net on this, or in Microsoft's documentation. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would rebuild your Connection using the FLATFILE type, then use it within a Foreach Loop Container that sets a Variable to the file name.  In the Connection definition, you can use an Expression to set the ConnectionString property to your Variable value.

Then you can use that Variable value to take whatever action you need when your "bad" condition occurs.

Comment: Thanks, but that's the way it currently works. I am modifying the package, and using the MULTIFLATFILE to improve performance. And, it definitely improves the performance, sucking up the data for 30 files at once instead of looping through them. Still have the problem of identifying which file fails. But at this point, I do not think there is a way to do this.

Comment: In that case I would split the DFT that loads each file into a sub-package, and use 30 un-constrained Execute Package Tasks to run in parallel.  Wrap each EPT in a Sequence Container so you can set the file variable for each instance, pass it as a Parent Package Variable.  Each execution of the sub-package can handle your "bad" condition requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Configure the FileNameColumnName property of the Flat File Source component. That will add a column containing the file name.